# Virtual hosts in nginx from outside in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, virtualhost

I am trying to run a project in docker with nginx + php-fpm. Ubuntu 20.10.

There is docker-compose from the standard examples:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./sites:/var/www
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./images/php
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./sites:/var/www
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /etc/mysql:/etc/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-files:/var/lib/mysql-files
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sait
```

Locally hosts are raised, in hosts I can specify virtual hosts and access them. How to make such a configuration refer to virtual hosts from the outside? A-records are registered, by the external IP-address I get correctly to the default project, and by the domain name - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
The ports are open to ufw, and it enters normally via the external ip.

nginx domain.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name ________ www.___________;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/________________;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
        && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mbstring mysqli pdo_mysql zip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/40-custom.ini

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

sudo lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN

```
systemd-r  605 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  26775      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd      667            root    6u  IPv6  29160      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      667            root    7u  IPv4  29161      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
container  777            root    8u  IPv4  31394      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:43289 (LISTEN)
sshd       803            root    3u  IPv4  30762      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       803            root    4u  IPv6  30764      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2342            root    4u  IPv6  40932      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2521            root    4u  IPv6  43169      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
docker-pr 2535            root    4u  IPv6  44053      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: There must be something wrong in your files in the hosts folder. Can you also post one of those?

Comment: the nginx config, is this inside container, or is it another nginx running on the host? EDIT: please provide the output of `netstat -tnlp` command from your host (not from inside containers)

Comment: This is the nginx config for the domain, inside container.
Added lsof -nP -i | grep LISTEN

Comment: Is the error shown by your webbrowser or happend in communication between the containers `nginx` and `php`?

Comment: @akop Error between remote web browser when trying to get to virtual host. Locally, I can get to the virtual host when it is specified in the hosts-file (127.0.0.1 domain.name)

Comment: What do you mean with "remote web browser"? Can you draw a simple image, where we can see how the systems are connected? (Maybe via draw.io)

Comment: There is a clean OS Ubuntu 20.10. It has folders (hosts with my_domain.conf, images with php (bulid by Dockerfile), sites/my_domain) and docker. The communication between containers is denoted in docker-compose.yml. The hosts folder contains ny_domain.conf (and links ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d).
In /etc/hosts - 127.0.0.1 my_domain. I have access to the site by domain name locally from this OS, but i can't  access the site by my_domain form outside PC. my_domain - it's real domain, A-records at DNS are correct. I can access the site (which default conf in hosts folder) by real server's ip.

Comment: I think the container listens 80 port from OS/from outside requests and should serve the specified virtual host, but I have ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: [Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hEz9.png)? And the communication between internet and your local maschine does not work?

Comment: @akop Scheme is ok. Communication doesn't work by virtual_host name, yes. But I can access to this default project via direct IP.

Comment: Can you reach your local maschine in the internet? Is the 80-port exposed to all in the internet?

Comment: @akop Yes, via direct real IP I can access to machine. I can connect to default host at nginx via real IP from other PC not from this network

Comment: Then I guess that's something wrong with your nginx-config.